# How do I post HTML form data to a php file another server using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am a bit of a noob with jQuery and am learning for Uni.

I am working on a HTML web site with an associated HTML mobile application that I will compile in phonegap build.

I have a HTML form that I want to include on both the site and the app which I have coded and is successfully validating with jQuery. I would also like to post the form data with jQuery but am struggling to find how best to achieve this.

My form looks like this

```
    <form action="http://myaddress.com/process.php" method="post" name="jform" id="jform">
    <div>
    <label for="name"><b>Name:</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="dob"><b>Date of Birth:</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="visit"><b>Date of Visit:</b></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="visit" id="visit">
    </div>
    <div class="labelBlock">
    <b>Favourite Exhibit:</b>
    <div class="indent">
            <input  type="radio" name="fave" id="exhibit1" value="Exhibit1">
            <label for="exhibit1">Exhibit 1</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="fave" id="exhibit2" value="Exhibit2">
            <label for="exhibit2">Exhibit 2</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="fave" id="exhibit3" value="Exhibit3">
            <label for="exhibit3">Exhibit 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="comment"><b>Comments:</b></label><br>
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="40" draggable="false"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="center-button">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="center-text">
    </div>
    </form>
```

My validation script looks like this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jform').validate({

    rules: {
    name: "required",
    dob: "required",
    visit: "required",
    fave: "required",
    comment: "required"
    }, //end rules
    messages: {
    name: {
    required: "Please tell us your name"
    },
    dob: {
    required: 'Please select your Date of Birth'
    },
    visit: {
    required: 'Please select the date you visited'
    },
    fave: {
    required: 'Please select your favourite exhibit'
    },
    comment: {
    required: 'Please tell us about your visit'
    }
    },//end messages

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
    if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
    error.appendTo( element.parent()); 
    } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
    } 
    } 
    }); // end validate 
    submitHandler: function(form) { //This is the submit handler. 
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var dob = $('#dob').val();
    var visit = $('#visit').val();
    var fave = $("input[name='fave']:radio:checked").val();
    var comment = $('#comment').val();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process-post.php',
    data: {name:name, dob:dob, visit:visit, fave:fave, comment:comment},
    success: function(data1){
    if (data1 == 'success') {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    }
    else {
    alert('Oops! It looks like something has gone wrong. Please try again.');
    }
    }
    });
    }}); // end ready
```

I really am struggling with this so would appreciate any help.

My PHP Looks like this

```
    <?php # PROCESS JOURNAL ENTRY.

    # Check form submitted.
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
    # Open database connection.
    require ( '../connect_db.php' ) ;

    # Execute inserting into 'forum' database table.
    $q = "INSERT INTO journal(name,dob,visit,fave,comment,date) 
    VALUES ('{$_POST[name]}','{$_POST[dob]}','{$_POST[visit]}','{$_POST[fave]}','{$_POST [comment]}',NOW() )";
    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q ) ;

    # Report error on failure.
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) != 1) { die ('Error' . mysqli_error($dbc)); } else { echo "success"; }

    # Close database connection.
    mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  This is a very powerful function that is used any time jQuery validation is used.  It also lets you submit to the PHP file and get the results without refreshing the page.

**EDIT:**

Depending on the complexity of your project, ajax may be overkill.  You can just normally submit the form after it is validated like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#jform').validate({

rules: {
name: "required",
dob: "required",
visit: "required",
fave: "required",
comment: "required"
}, //end rules
messages: {
name: {
required: "Please tell us your name"
},
dob: {
required: 'Please select your Date of Birth'
},
visit: {
required: 'Please select the date you visited'
},
fave: {
required: 'Please select your favourite exhibit'
},
comment: {
required: 'Please tell us about your visit'
}
},//end messages

errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
if ( element.is(":radio") ) {
error.appendTo( element.parent()); 
} else {
error.insertAfter(element);
} 
} 
}); // end validate

submitHandler: function(form) { //This is the submit handler.  
    $(form).submit();
}

}); // end ready
</script>
```

Here is the part that I add:

```
submitHandler: function(form) { //This is the submit handler.  
    $(form).submit();
}
```

This will submit a form normally, meaning that it will run the PHP script and then refresh the page.

If you decide you want to use ajax, you can just replace `$(form).submit();` with this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var dob= $('#dob').val();
var visit = $('#visit').val();
var fave = $("input[type='radio'][name='fave']:checked").val();
var comment = $('#comment').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://myaddress.com/process.php',
    data: {name:name, dob:dob, visit:visit, fave:fave, comment:comment},
    success: function(data){
        if (data == 'success') {
            //do something
        }
        else {
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

The `data` that I am using in the success portion of the function is the value returned from the PHP script.  Since you mentioned comments, I am assuming that you PHP is not returning data, but more or less a completion message.  In that case, you would just have your PHP `echo 'success';` if it was successful.  Then fill in the "do somethings" in the jQuery.

Comment: Also recommend using this plugin, helps when you have a lot of input fields, dont have to collect them manually: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Having looked at the link provided this does seem to be the way to go. Is it possible to add the code to my existing script and if so where should I put it?

Comment: @user3192433 Ajax is asynchronous, so it will run in parallel with any other code on its level.  So if you want it to run after the validation, you will need to put the ajax inside an if loop with the validation as a condition.

Comment: Thanks, but you have lost me a bit. Any chance of an example?

Comment: @user3192433 I am a bit tied up at the moment, but I will try to put something together tonight or tomorrow morning.

Comment: @user3192433 See my edit.  The validation you are using will handle some of it for you.

Comment: Thanks that's great but dreamweaver is telling me there is syntax error on this line var fave = $('input[type='radio'][name='fave']:checked').val();

Comment: It should be double quotes around the selector, not single.

Comment: Spot on thank you. I am having another problem now. The form is posting the data to the php correctly and the php is returning success. But when it returns success it is not loading the index.html page as instructed.

Comment: I have updated my code in my first post. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @user3192433 location.href needs an absolute URL:  `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html` instead of `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he is correct jquery's ajax will accomplish this or http post. You will use one of the mentioned methods to get the data from the HTML form and send it to the sever.

Comment: If you agree, try upvoting answers instead of copying them.